# What is wrong with this "adiabatic" process?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, ideal-gas

I came across the following problem:

The volume of a cylinder is separated by a piston. There is some ideal gas at temperature $T_0$ and volume $V_0$ at one side of the piston and a spring at the other side.The piston is initially fixed so that the spring has the equilibrium length.  Being relaxed the piston comes to an equilibrium position such that the gas volume becomes $V_1$. Find the new temperature of the ideal gas. Both the cylinder walls and piston are thermal insulators.

This assumed to be a school problem and it is easily solved assuming that the internal energy of the gas is given by $U=c_V n T$ and that the "lost" portion of the internal gas energy transfers to the potential energy of the spring.

However somebody with a high-school knowledge can consider this as an adiabatic process and use simply the equation $TV^{\gamma-1}=\text{const}$.

The problem is that the two solutions are different. Which of the two solutions is in error and what is the source of the error?

Comment: When you say "being relaxed" are you saying the piston is released allowing the gas to rapidly expand until equilibrium is reached?

Comment: @BobD If the mass of the piston is sufficiently large the process will be sufficiently slow.

Comment: so you are saying the piston is not massless?

Comment: @BobD The problem says nothing about the mass of the piston. The answer also seemingly does not depend on the mass. If you see that this is the key to resolve the contradiction I would appreciate the proof.

Comment: If the piston has mass then the gas doing work on the piston and not just the spring. Your description of the problem statement is insufficient to solve it. Have you given us the entire description of the problem?

Comment: @BobD The entire description of the problem is given. You may assume that the mass of the piston is very large (so that its motion is very slow) and demonstrate that this gives the adiabatic equation. I will very appreciate this.

Comment: you say that "The problem is that the two solutions are different". What two solutions are you referring to?

Comment: @BobD The solutions $$\frac{T_0}{T_1}=1+\frac{\gamma-1}2\left(1-\frac{V_0}{V_1}\right)$$ and $$\frac{T_0}{T_1}=\left(\frac{V_1}{V_0}\right)^{\gamma-1}.$$

Answer (score 3):

> However somebody with a high-school knowledge can consider this as an
> adiabatic process and use simply the equation
> $TV^{\gamma-1}=\text{const}$.

$TV^{\gamma-1}=\text{const}$ is the equation for a reversible adiabatic expansion (or compression) process for of an ideal gas. A reversible expansion must occur very slowly (quasi-statically).

The details of your process were not given, But if the piston is released and the gas allowed to rapidly expand against the spring the process is irreversible and the equation does not apply. Then you can only apply the ideal gas law to the initial and final equilibrium states.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If the mass of the piston is sufficiently large the process will be sufficiently slow.

Comment: @drer so you are saying the piston is not massless?

Comment: The problem says nothing about the mass of the piston. The answer also seemingly does not depend on the mass. If you see that this is the key to resolve the contradiction I would appreciate the proof. I would assume that the mass is sufficiently large to make the process slow (adiabatic).

Comment: Even if we know it is a reversible adiabatic process, there is still insufficient information. The adiabatic index, $\gamma$ for an ideal gas depends on if it is a monatomic gas, diatomic gas, etc. and you are not given that information.

Comment: You may assume that this information is given (for example as the ratio $\gamma=C_p/C_V$). In the original problem the relation $U=cT$ (with a known $c$) was given.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a linear spring, the external force exerted by the spring on the piston is $$F=P_1A\frac{V-V_0}{V_1-V_0}$$where A is the area of the piston, $P_1$ is the final pressure of the gas, and V is the gas volume during the deformation.  The external work done by spring on the gas is $$W_S=-\int{Fdx}=-\int{P_1\frac{V-V_0}{V_1-V_0}Adx}=-\int_{V_0}^{V_1}{P_1\frac{V-V_0}{V_1-V_0}dV}=-P_1\frac{V_1-V_0}{2}$$So the work done by the gas on the spring (the surroundings) is $$W_G=P_1\frac{V_1-V_0}{2}=nRT_1\frac{1-V_0/V_1}{2}$$So, for this adiabatic expansion, $$nC_V(T_1-T_0)=-nRT_1\frac{1-V_0/V_1}{2}$$

Comment: This is the alleged correct solution (apart from an error in the integration). My question was however why the adiabatic equation does not hold.

Comment: You suggest that, if the piston had a large enough mass, the process would be both adiabatic and reversible, and your equation would apply.  Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Because the question is closed I asked a new one where I tried to clarify the core of the question.

Comment: I don't see it anywhere.  Where is the thread located?  If you keep getting problems with the moderators closing your threads at this site, consider submitting your question(s) to PhysicsForums.com.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/772416/a-problem-involving-adiabatic-expansion-of-ideal-gas

Answer (score -1):

Sure looks adiabatic --- so I'd use $pV^\gamma$- constant....I feel that the original problem may have some other information given. Otherwise how could you even figure out the energy in the spring? If just released the spring would alos gain kinetic energy. If released gradually there is other work than that done on the spring.

Comment: No other information is given (except for the relation $U=cT$).

Comment: Then how did you get the "wrong" answer?

Comment: From $U(T_0)=U(T_1)+\frac{k(x_1-x_0)^2}2$ and $p_1A=k(x_1-x_0)$ ($A$ is the cross-section area) as well as the state equation of the ideal gas.

Comment: But you were not given $k$, and also you are ignoring the the kinetic energy of the piston, which will oscillato unless there is friction.

Comment: That is an interesting idea. There is no friction. Could you demonstrate that the piston will oscillate without coming to rest?

Comment: Well there is a spring one side and gas on the other. It does not start in equilibrium, so the pistons will accelerate, overshoot and come back, and, in the absence of friction will bounce back and forth  for ever.

Comment: Sounds like a badly stated problem. Where di you get it from?

Comment: A friend of me give it as a problem from an old Olympic in physics.

Comment: Could you demonstrate that assuming sufficiently large mass of the piston the temperature of the gas at any moment will obey the adiabatic equation?

Comment: The process will be adiabatic provided that the piston moves significantl slower than the speed of sound in the gas. A standard example is measuring $\gamma$ by dropping a ball bearing in a tight-fitting tube: https://www.ucl.ac.uk/~zcapf71/Measurement%20of%20Cp.pdf

Comment: apparaently this is called the "Rüchardt experiment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rüchardt_experiment    We did it in high school.

Comment: Thank you. I never heard of this experiment.  I will check if it helps me. My ultimate aim is to demonstrate that the energy conservation law for the system under consideration leads to the adiabatic equation. Hopefully the elimination of the assumption that the piston comes to rest removes the contradiction.